# Set in useState hook resulting in empty

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

In my code:

```
const applicationState: ApplicationState = useSelector(applicationState => applicationState)
let siteSet = applicationState.favoriteSiteSet
if (!siteSet) {
    siteSet = new Set<number>()
}
const [favSite, setFavSite] = useState(siteSet)
```

Here, `siteSet` has some elements. However, when I use `useState` hook on `siteSet` to get `favSite`, it returns empty set.

What is the reason for this? Do I need to add the value manually after `useState`?

Comment: can you full component code or console.log(applicationState) to show what you get

Comment: const [favSite, setFavSite] = useState(()=>siteSet) once try this or better created codesandbox

Comment: @JohnLobo Thanks. It worked. It should be the answer. Any reason why it worked?

Comment: @JohnLobo You should post that as an answer.

Comment: @doptimusprime.I am also newbe to reactjs.recently i learnt a bit about usestate lazy initialization.i thought it might be the reason .it was just guessed actually

Comment: you only have problems because you are trying to copy props to state. Don't do this. You don't need useState for your use case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look like your useState initial value  fetching from api.So useState Lazy initialization is better way to do by using callback.

```
const [favSite, setFavSite] = useState(()=>siteSet)
```

Comment: This answer makes no sense. It has nothing to do with "lazy initialization". Even in the article you linked it says lazy initialization is only meant for performance optimization, not for changing the logic

Comment: @max.as i said in above comment it was my guessed answer.since use state taking time to set initial value.you can see my post comments.

Comment: @Max.could you post exact answer what could be the sollution so both op and i can learn how to solve it

Comment: even question doesn't have  full code i given sollution based on code  what provided in  question

Comment: @JohnLobo File being changed is at https://github.com/devendermishra/check-my-vaccine/blob/main/src/components/Result.tsx
It is still in work in progress.

Comment: @doptimusprime.no problem .look like my solution isn't an elegant solution .make sure to read what max said

Answer (score 0):

Try to update the value of favSite in useEffect.
so when the value is available it will update itself.
e.g

```
useEffect(()=> {
 siteSet = applicationState.favoriteSiteSet
  if (!siteSet) {
   siteSet = new Set<number>()
   setFavSite(siteSet)
  }
}, [])
```

Comment: But this useEffect runs only once when the component is mounted . Inorder for the siteSet to be in sync with the local component state , we need to add the `siteSet` as the dependency to the `useEffect`

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that, at the time this component is mounted, the value for `applicationState` is `undefined`.
Since you didn't provide any way to update `favSite`, when the `applicationState` is updated, the `favSite` still maintains its original value.[The previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67856819/9087143) provided a solution for this problem.

Comment: I debugged that. `applicationState` had values and set has one element. But once I used it in useState, the result was an empty set.